# limsup in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. random variables $X_n$. We have the inequality:
$$P(\liminf{X_n\leq x})\leq \liminf P({X_n\leq x})\leq \limsup P({X_n\leq x})\leq P(\limsup{X_n≤x})$$

Is there any way to prove (or any conditions under which) that:

$$\log P({X_n ≤x}) \leq \limsup \frac 1n P({X_n \leq x})$$

Comment: Probabilities output values in $[0,1]$. Therefore, their logarithms output values in $[-\infty,0]$. Since $0\leq\frac{1}{n}P(X_n\leq x)$, then also $0\leq\limsup\frac{1}{n}P(X_n\leq x)$. Transitivity yields $\log P(X_n\leq x)\leq \limsup \frac{1}{n}P(X_n\leq x)$.

Comment: "a sequence of $n$ iid..." I think you want to remove the $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\log P(X_n \leq x) \leq 0$ and $ \lim \sup \frac 1 n P(X_n \leq x)=0$ so the inequality is always true.

Comment: Another, related question: Consider a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_n$. Is there any way to prove (or any conditions under which) that:

$\log P\left( X_n \geq x \right)$ 
$ \leq \limsup_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \log P\left(X_n \geq x \right)$